# Accessing Elements in Complex JSON Nested Object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to web scrape some embedded Youtube URLs, by way of dumping the data into a JSON array:

The code to build the JSON array is as follows:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.brooklynvegan.com/andy-shauf-shares-new-single-spanish-on-the-beach-tour-starts-next-week/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')[30].string.strip()[26:]
data = json.loads(script)
```

From here, if I access a single element in the array ('558725') by it's full path, this correctly pulls me back the iframe tag I'm looking for:

```
iframe_tag = data['json']['response']['widgets']['carbonwidget/single-1']\
    ['dataDetails']['558725']['podContent'][3]['data']['html']
print(iframe_tag)
```

```
<iframe width="200" height="113" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lD1a2tfDC0c?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, if I try to break this down into a loop in case there are more elements in the list, I start to encounter a "string indices must be integers" error:

```
for data_detail_no in data['json']['response']['widgets']['carbonwidget/single-1']['dataDetails']:
    print(data_detail_no['podContent'][3]['data']['html'])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/back2/PycharmProjects/RSS-Scraper/new-attempt.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(data_detail_no['podContent'][3]['data']['html'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The relevant part of the JSON structure is as follows:

```
          "dataDetails": {
            "558725": {
              "podContent": [
                {
                  "cumulativePodTextLength": 586,
                  "currentTextLength": 586,
                  "data": {
```

The full json object can be accessed from:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aarzpf7jz3aig15/articledump2.json?dl=0

I don't hit another list until further down the structure, so I'm not certain why I'm hitting this  error, I'd have thought the code should just loop around the list at the point I've made the slice. If I amend my code to simply print the dataDetail number, no errors are generated.

```
for data_detail_no in data['json']['response']['widgets']['carbonwidget/single-1']['dataDetails']:
    print(data_detail_no)
```

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong with this please?

Comment: share `data` and explain what is the expected output

Comment: I've added the link to the main article, also here for a copy of the full JSON object (it's essentially the webpage contents converted into JSON)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aarzpf7jz3aig15/articledump2.json?dl=0

What I'm trying to get is an iframe tag the same as when I specify the absolute path (or multiple iframe tags should multiple embedded videos be present, although in the page I'm scraping there's only one).

Comment: dataDetails is a `dict`, so in that last part it looks like you're just looping over the keys in the dict object (which always come as strings in JSON). I guess what you want is `for data_detail_no, val in <long path to datadetails>.items():`

Comment: For your example above where you were getting the error, just add on a `.values()` at the end, and it should work. This will iterate over the values, instead of keys which you get with the `for key in dict` syntax.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yes, fantastic, that's solved it. The tutorials I was looking at all had string or integer objects at that level rather than dictionaries, that explains where I was getting confused as the syntax was identical as far as I could see, Thank you so much!

`for v in data['json']['response']['widgets']['carbonwidget/single-1']['dataDetails'].values():
    print(v['podContent'][3]['data']['html'])`